# ajaxurl not defined on front end

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, ajax, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to create a ajaxform on the front side. I am using the code

```
    jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: formData,
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
```

for which I am getting error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxurl is not definedworklorAjaxBookForm @ 
?page_id=2:291onclick @ ?page_id=2:202
```

While using similar code on the admin backend works. What url must I use to process the ajax request?

Comment: Check this tutorial. It may help you. http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/implement-ajax-wordpress-themes/

Answer (score 74, accepted):

In backend there is global `ajaxurl` variable defined by WordPress itself.

This variable is not created by WP in frontend. It means that if you want to use AJAX calls in frontend, then you have to define such variable by yourself.

Good way to do this is to use `wp_localize_script`.

Let's assume your AJAX calls are in `my-ajax-script.js` file, then add wp_localize_script for this JS file like so:

```
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

After localizing your JS file, you can use `my_ajax_object` object in your JS file:

```
jQuery.ajax(
    {
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data: formData,
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can I use `wp_localize_script` without having to use `wp_enqueue_scritp`?

Comment: You use script handle in wp_localize_script, so you have to use wp_enqueue_script for at least one of your scripts. But... Not using wp_enqueue_script is not a good idea (you risk some conflicts and dependencies problems).

Comment: i don't have any external script to load, i just want to use ajaxurl to make an ajax call. is that not possible?

Comment: And where will you put this AJAX call? As inline script? It's a very bad idea...

Comment: i've a separate form, in that i'm managing validation and on submit, an ajax call to submit form with of course wordpress way by adding hook. anyway I've figured out the way for using ajaxurl.

Comment: Awesome... I'm using it in my Javascript on front end and works like a charm :)

Comment: I don't understand. What if the calls are made from multiple separate files? How do you proceede then? Can't you just "declare" a single ajax url for the whole WP instance? And why isn't that automatically done?

Comment: Since a while there is `wp_add_inline_script()` which said to be a more modern and cleaner alternative to the good old `wp_localize_script()` for these specific ajax cases.

Answer (score 56):

to use ajaxurl directly, in your plugin file add this:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'myplugin_ajaxurl');

function myplugin_ajaxurl() {

   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           var ajaxurl = "' . admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '";
         </script>';
}
```

you can then use the `ajaxurl` for ajax request.

Comment: This answer makes `ajaxurl` similarly the same as the default usage. Which is much better than the accepted answer.

Comment: true, but it's useless if you are using it in a .js file.

Comment: @Jules `ajaxurl` is still available in a `*.js` file. To do so, you may need to declare the `ajaxurl` variable early on of the page load. Another thing to consider is the calling of the external `*.js` file of yours. The external file should be called **AFTER** the `ajaxurl` has been instantiated and be given the right URL value.

Comment: what's an error in console?

Comment: What about conflicts with other plugins or themes that declare the variable in the same way? I do believe you should at least namespace the variable. Anyway, I think the accepted answer has less potential to cause trouble/conflicts later on. But I guess if you are well aware what you are doing, this approach is fine.

Answer (score 3):

The 2021 way is a bit different ;-)

```
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_add_inline_script( 'ajax-script', 
        'const myVariables = ' . json_encode( 
                                    array(
                                        'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                                        ) ),
        'before' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/#comment-4632

Comment: I just stumbled across this same solution today, there's [more information](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) regarding when to use `wp_add_inline_script()` vs `wp_localize_script()` on the wp_localize_script documentation too, if you're curious.

Answer (score 0):

i have use below code in wordpress site.
we can use below code for setup ajaxurl like this.

```
<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); ?>
```

i have also added ajax example were we can use above line.

```
 function setNotificationRead() {
        fetch('<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-ajax.php')); ?>', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: `action=yourFunctionsAction`,
            credentials: 'same-origin'
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(data => {
            if (data.status === 'true') {
                console.log('Do something...');
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work after many hours...and trials and errors. So, I do share how to make ajax work in wordpress with an example (started with https://www.tweaking4all.com/web-development/wordpress/wordpress-ajax-example/#comment-562814 and adapted the example)

--use chrome developer tools and take off cache from network tab
--look to console if you get any errors, first goal is to get to console "ready!" when you click the button and if all works you get some nice output too!

--add to wordpress website as custom html block:

```
<div id="receiving_div_id">
   <p>Nothing loaded yet</p>
</div>
<button id="button_to_load_data">Get Ajax Content</button>
```

--add to theme/js/button.js (create js folder):

```
   jQuery("#button_to_load_data").click(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
      var data = {
         'action'   : 't4a_ajax_call', // the name of your PHP function!
         'function' : 'show_files',    // a random value we'd like to pass
         'fileid'   : '7'              // another random value we'd like to pass
         };
       
      jQuery.post(my_ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
         jQuery("#receiving_div_id").html(response);
      });
   });
```

--add to theme functions.php:

```
 /* custom script in theme functions.php */

/* read button.js (->my-script) and localize admin-ajax.php for my-script */
function add_my_script() {

  wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 
         get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/button.js', 
         array ( 'jquery' ), 
         false,
         true
  );
  
      wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'my_ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );



/*ajax result */

add_action('wp_ajax_t4a_ajax_call', 't4a_ajax_call');  // for logged in users only
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_t4a_ajax_call', 't4a_ajax_call'); // for ALL users

function t4a_ajax_call(){

   echo 'Ajax call output:';

   echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($_POST);
   echo '</pre>';

   wp_die();// this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```